# How to match the match just behind a positive lookahead when there are multiple matches, in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex,

I have a sample text

```
abcd

efgh 

ijk

DOB
```

I wanted to match only the line occurring just behind DOB

I tried:

```
(?P<name>a-zA-Z)(?=DOB)
```

but this doesn't work,

How to match only ijk?

Comment: Are those empty lines actually present in the input?

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes

Comment: The pattern `(?P<name>a-zA-Z)(?=DOB)` does not match anything for the given example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a multiline regular expression:

```py
print(re.search('(?m)^([a-zA-Z]+)$\s*(?=DOB)', s).group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match the regular expression

```
(?mi)^[a-z]+(?=(?:\r?\n)+DOB\r?\n)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vharko/1)

The expression has the following elements.

```
(?mi)         # match the remainder with the flags m and i
^             # match the beginning of the line
[a-z]+        # match one or more letters
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:\r?\n)+  # match one or more line terminators
  DOB\r?\n    # match 'DOB' followed by a line terminator
)             # end the positive lookahead
```

The *multiline* flag `m` (in `(?mi)`) causes `^` to match the start and end of a line. The *case insensitive* flag `i` causes `[a-z]` to match any lowercase or uppercase letter. `\r` is needed if the file was created on a computer using Windows. `\r?` makes it optional.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex pattern for what you want to achieve:

```
[^\n]+(?=\nDOB)
```

[Verify here](https://regex101.com/r/2neZw3/1)

Explanation:

- `[^\n]+`: a negated character class with a quantifier which says match ONE or MORE of any characters **except a new line**
- `(?=\nDOB)`: lookahead which asserts that the string is followed by a new line and literal DOB

This way you get the string, before the last line.